# Using Hibernate .hbm in addition to annotations

Tags: hibernate

I have a bunch of autogenerated files that look similar to the following one:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FooType", propOrder = {
    "bar",
    "foobar"
})
@Entity(name = "FooType")
@Table(name = "FOOTYPE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class FooType
    implements Serializable, Equals, HashCode {
   // more stuff
}
```

These files are generated from a XML-Schema. What I need to do is adding caching capabilities to these classes. While there are various ways to add annotations to it, I'm required to use mapping files (.hbm.xml).

I've read somewhere that you can use `.hbm.xml` and annotations side by side, but when I've tried adding an `hbm` file like this one:

I got an `org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException`. So, is it actually possible? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all annotations to be ignorred then don't use `AnnotationConfiguration` or `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`. Use `Configuration` or `LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead.

Comment: The annotations are perfectly fine, what I want is some sort of "merging" the two configurations together.

Comment: In this case, I'd just put together my own extension of `Configuration` based on `AnnotationConfiguration` source code and put all logic there.